# Python threading - Change variable value in another class

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am looking for a way to change the variables between classes in different threads.
As I had a question about threading recently, I'd like to use that example code for this question again.

Main-File:

```
#PROGRAM/SCRIPT
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
import GUI
import datetime
import pyqtgraph
import time
plotsize = 20


class Worker2(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Thread2 has been started")
        
    def run(self):
        #now get access to variable of class Worker
        
# =============================================================================
# Threading for not freezing the GUI while running
# =============================================================================
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    widgetplot = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list, list)

    def __init__(self, plot_time, plot_value):
        print("Thread has been started")
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, objectName='WorkerThread')
        self.plot_time = plot_time
        self.plot_value = plot_value

    def run(self):
        #now get access to variable of Worker2
        _count = 0

        _start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        while 0 <= _count < 100:
            # Use local variable!
            _count_prev = _count
            QtCore.QThread.usleep(10000)
            _diff = datetime.datetime.now() - _start_time
            _count = int((_diff.total_seconds() * 10))
            if(_count != _count_prev):
                print(_count)
                x = self.plot_time[:_count]
                y = self.plot_value[:_count]
                self.widgetplot.emit(x, y)


class my_class(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, GUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(my_class, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.WidgetPlot.setXRange(0, 105, padding=0)
        self.WidgetPlot.setYRange(0, 105, padding=0)

        self.second_line = pyqtgraph.PlotDataItem(pen=pyqtgraph.mkPen('w', width=plotsize*2))
        
        self.plot_time = []
        self.plot_value = []

        self.worker_thread = Worker(self.plot_time, self.plot_value)

        self.worker_thread.widgetplot.connect(self.update_second_line_plot)

        self.worker_thread2 = Worker2()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.my_function)

        self.WidgetPlot.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.WidgetPlot.getAxis("bottom").setTickFont(font)
        self.WidgetPlot.getAxis("left").setTickFont(font)


    def my_function(self):
        _l = list(range(100))
        self.plot_time.extend(_l)
        self.plot_value.extend(_l)

        self.start()
        
    def update_second_line_plot(self, plot_time, plot_value):
        self.second_line.setData(plot_time, plot_value)


    def start(self):
        self.WidgetPlot.plot(self.plot_time, self.plot_value, pen=pyqtgraph.mkPen('r', width=plotsize))

        self.WidgetPlot.addItem(self.second_line)
    
        self.worker_thread.start() 
        self.worker_thread2.start()
    


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = my_class()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

GUI:

```
#GUI.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(739, 532)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.WidgetPlot = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.WidgetPlot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 541, 341))
        self.WidgetPlot.setObjectName("WidgetPlot")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 420, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Window"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'd like to change variable in class Worker2 from class Worker and vice versa.

Many thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: Re, "I'd like to change variable in class Worker2 from class Worker and vice versa." That's the opposite of object-oriented programming. In OO, each object keeps its own _private_ state, and if the object is mutable, it can only be mutated by the methods declared in that object's class. Allowing objects to directly access each other's state is an anti-pattern. It's an undisciplined style that can work for small programs, but which cannot be scaled up to large software systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is 130 lines of code but no variable because this is my question. How to add that it can be changed from outside. To your last reply: How to start the thread/how to refer to the class. It's called by starting the thread but for the other class there is no way to call/change variables...

Comment: Deleted my comment about 130 lines. Retracted my close vote. I hope that my answer (below) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> but for the other class there is no way to call/change variables...

Member variables* in Python are public by default.** Suppose you have

```py
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = "whatever"
    def printit(self):
        print(self.q)
```

You can do this in the repl:

```
>>> p = P()
p = P()
>>> p.printit()
p.printit()
whatever
>>> p.q
p.q
'whatever'
>>> p.q = 'new value'
p.q = 'new value'
>>> p.printit()
p.printit()
new value
>>> p.q
p.q
'new value'
```

You can do the same from *anywhere* in Python code that has a reference to an object belonging to `class P`.

---

* "Attributes?" "fields?" I wrote a lot of Python programs that were ancillary to projects that I worked on—mostly for my own use. I haven't talked a lot with other Python programmers, and I don't really know the lingo.

** See https://towardsdatascience.com/private-protected-attributes-in-python-demystified-once-and-for-all-9456d4e56414 for more about "public" vs. "private."

Comment: Thanks. As my class "Worker" expects by calling it two variables, something like p = P() is not possible. Right here is the problem. I cant define p = Worker() as it must be some kind like p = Worker(var1, var2). But this variables were already send by defining the thread. So if I call it again with variables I'd change them when the program is already running.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. I don't know what "variables were already send by defining the thread" means. I don't know what "call it again with variables" means. I suggest you write a new question. Put the code that you wish would work for you in the new question, and explain why it doesn't work. (I.e., if it gets errors that you don't undertsand, then include the error messages in your question. If it behaves differently from the way you expect, then please describe both your expected behavior and the actual behavior.)